# Webpack dependencies from index.ts resolved in wrong order

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

We heavily rely on `moduleResolution: 'node'` in our latest project. We generated index.ts barrels to simpify the import statements. However, when building the app with webpack, the modules seem to be resolved in the wrong order:

I have a file `iconSet.ts`

```
export var IconSet = {
    Add: 'icon-add',
    Remove: 'icon-remove'
}
```

a second file `icons.ts`, which imports the IconSet variable

```
import { IconSet } from '.'

export var Icons = {
    Add: IconSet.Add,
    Remove: IconSet.Remove
}
```

and a index.ts file, that rollsup all exports like

```
export * from './icons'
export * from './iconSet'
```

When importing the Icons variable in an app.ts, icons.ts is provided before inconSet.ts was processes.

```
import { Icons } from '.'
console.log(Icons); // <- Cannot read property 'Add' of undefined
```

I thought webpack would take care of this.

Here is a minimal repo to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/eulbot/webpack-es6-index-barrels

Answer (score 2):

We've faced similar problem in our projects. As a solution we used changing order of export lines, e.g.:

`export * from './iconSet'
export * from './icons'`

Should work.

It looks like if **ClassA** imports **ClassB**, then **ClassB** should be placed before **ClassA** in the **index.d.ts** file.

Also, you might consider importing classes from each other and not from the **index.d.ts**. We found that if classes are imported directly from class files (e.g. **IconSet** would be imported from the **iconSet.ts** file), then **Webpack + ts-loader** correctly import dependencies.

Comment: As mentioned above, we have quite a large codebase and generate those index.js files automatically. I can't believe that webpack doesn't handlle those dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 1):

At least with Node 9.3.0 on MacOs, the sample repo you've provided appears to function as expected.

The output is: `{ Add: 'icon-add', Remove: 'icon-remove' }`

I tried both `development` and `production` modes with the webpack cli. That's `node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli --mode=development`.

I'm currently wrestling with a similar problem that I hope is the result of circular references, [something like this old issue.](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2759)

Comment: Can you try pulling the latest version, I accidentally pushed the "right" order of exports in the index.js file